# Making this pandas code as lean and speedy as possible? [iterating over large DataFrames and setting]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

For context, my master dataset is a 24541 row x 1830 column DataFrame full of either NaN or a float (stock price). I am processing this DataFrame 11 times, each time setting values in a casted DataFrame with the same index and columns. An example of both DataFrames is below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filepath)
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data, dtype=np.float64)

#dataset of daily prices
data.head()

Out[14]: 
            49154  65541  32791  65568  ...  24563  81910  24571  90110
DATE                                    ...                            
1925-12-31    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1926-01-02    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1926-01-04    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1926-01-05    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1926-01-06    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN

[5 rows x 1830 columns]

MA_a_frame = pd.DataFrame(
        data=0,
        index=data.index, 
        columns=data.columns)

#bool DataFrame
MA_a_frame.head()

Out[15]: 
            49154  65541  32791  65568  ...  24563  81910  24571  90110
DATE                                    ...                            
1925-12-31      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0
1926-01-02      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0
1926-01-04      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0
1926-01-05      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0
1926-01-06      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0

[5 rows x 1830 columns]
```

The values in MA_a_frame (and 10 other identical DataFrames) are to be set to 1 if a certain condition in the DataFrame "data" is met. Namely, if the price in "data" is within 1% (argument is "j") of a calculated value in a **completely different** DataFrame generated in a previous function. So in total, each iteration will deal with up to 3 large DataFrames.

In terms of my iterator, I simply create two separate lists ("dates" and "securities") using data.columns and data.index. So I am essentially iterating over data's index and columns indirectly. Without further ado, here is the base of the code that is run a total of 11 times in my program (the part I am trying to speed up!):

```
def gen_a():

    for date in dates:

        for security in securities: 

            try: 

                if type(data.loc[date, security]) is not float:

                    pass
                    #lots of the data is NaN, so skip these altogether

                elif j > math.log(
                        MA_a_csv.loc[date, security]/
                        data.loc[date, security]) > -j:

                    MA_dict['a'].loc[date, security] = 1

                print(f'Passed {date}, {security}')

            except: 

                print(f'Failed {date}, {security}')
```

Now, the problem is one cycle of this code takes ~8 hours. Thus, I'm looking at nearly 90 hours per run. I have an academic paper due as a graduation requirement, and the deadline is really starting to scare me with these numbers! Assuming my output is perfect, things should be fine, but I would be eternally grateful if anyone had a suggestion that could cut the speed down. Otherwise, I may have to cut the range of the data down, reducing the power of my statistical analysis.

P.S. I am running this through Spyder on Windows 10 with an Intel i7 3970X. I do not have access to any other computing power. I considered GPU acceleration but my GPU is a GTX 670 which is not Pascal and thus incompatible with CuDF.

Edit:

Here's the bottom five rows of the data DataFrame:

```
s.head()
Out[16]: 
            49154      65541  32791  65568  ...  24563  81910  24571  90110
DATE                                        ...                            
2018-12-24  61.55  232.70000    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  15.71    NaN    NaN
2018-12-26  65.11  244.59000    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  16.48    NaN    NaN
2018-12-27  64.71  252.17999    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  16.71    NaN    NaN
2018-12-28  64.96  249.64999    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  16.55    NaN    NaN
2018-12-31  66.09  254.50000    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  16.74    NaN    NaN

[5 rows x 1830 columns]
```

And here's a sample of one of the comparison DataFrames:

```
Out[23]: 
              49154       65541  32791  65568  ...  24563    81910  24571  90110
DATE                                           ...                              
2018-12-24  76.3430  258.376200    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  19.8672    NaN    NaN
2018-12-26  75.9530  258.143600    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  19.7980    NaN    NaN
2018-12-27  75.5552  258.127199    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  19.7238    NaN    NaN
2018-12-28  75.1382  257.878799    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  19.6440    NaN    NaN
2018-12-31  74.7716  257.683199    NaN    NaN  ...    NaN  19.5600    NaN    NaN

[5 rows x 1830 columns]
```

Edit 2:

By request, here is data.head().to_dict():

```
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '44792': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85753': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20220': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12044': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20239': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28433': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12052': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12060': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): 326.0,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): 326.5,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): 325.0,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): 325.5,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): 326.25},
 '12062': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85792': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12067': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77605': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77606': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20263': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12073': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12076': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12079': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): 117.5,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): 124.25,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): 127.125,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): 123.75,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): 124.5},
 '61241': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12095': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28484': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '53065': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20298': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77644': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28505': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '53081': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77659': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12124': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77661': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28513': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '61284': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77668': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12140': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85869': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20343': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28548': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77702': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12167': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85908': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12183': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): 78.5,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): 78.0,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): 77.5,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): 76.875,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): 76.5},
 '44951': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85913': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85914': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12191': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20386': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77730': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28580': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85926': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20394': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '69550': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12212': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20407': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12220': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20415': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77768': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85963': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20431': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '45014': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '61399': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '69607': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '85991': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '53225': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20474': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20482': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '86021': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '45065': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12298': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '69649': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12308': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20503': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '45081': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '86041': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12319': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20511': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12343': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12345': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20554': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12369': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20562': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '86102': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20570': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '86111': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12394': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): 123.5,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): 124.0,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): 123.25,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): 123.5,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): 122.75},
 '36978': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '86136': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28804': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '86158': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12431': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '61583': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20626': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '77976': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '53401': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '86176': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12449': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '69796': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12456': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '45225': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '12458': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '20650': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 '28847': {Timestamp('1925-12-31 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('1926-01-06 00:00:00'): nan},
 ...}
```

Unfortunately, I am out of space for this post, but MA_a_csv.head().to_dict() produces the same as above except all NaN rather than the one data point.

Comment: Can you provide a sample where the dataframes actually have values, or dfs of dummy values? This looks, on the surface, like an operation that could and should be vectorized using boolean masking, but without usable inputs and desired outputs it's hard to know how to help

Comment: Sorry, the whole process is very convoluted. I edited my OP.

Comment: Hi R. Young, could you please update your question with the output of `data..head().to_dict()` and the same for the comparison df?

Comment: And have a read at [mcve](/help/mcve). Your example is not reproducible.

Comment: One possibility: Make an intermediate DF with `df3=np.log(df1/df2)` and use `np.where` to mask or set the values based on j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made my own sample data generator based on the examples you gave. I think it fits what you have, but let me know if it doesn't. If the data matches, don't worry about the specifics of how I made it.

```py
rows = 6
cols = 5
np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(rows, cols) * 100, 
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='d', start='1928-12-31', periods=rows))
nan_cols = len(data.columns) // 2
random_indices = zip(pd.Series(data.index.values[:-rows // 2])
                     .sample(nan_cols, random_state=1, replace=True), 
                     pd.Series(data.columns).sample(nan_cols, random_state=2))
for row, col in random_indices:
    data.loc[:row, col] = np.nan

MA_a_csv = data * (1 + (np.random.rand(rows, cols) / 50 
                        * np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=(rows, cols))))
```

So `data` looks like

```
                    0          1          2          3          4
1928-12-31  54.881350  71.518937        NaN  54.488318        NaN
1929-01-01  64.589411  43.758721        NaN  96.366276  38.344152
1929-01-02  79.172504  52.889492  56.804456  92.559664   7.103606
1929-01-03   8.712930   2.021840  83.261985  77.815675  87.001215
1929-01-04  97.861834  79.915856  46.147936  78.052918  11.827443
1929-01-05  63.992102  14.335329  94.466892  52.184832  41.466194
```

And `MA_a_csv` looks like

```
                    0          1          2          3          4
1928-12-31  55.171734  72.626384        NaN  55.107778        NaN
1929-01-01  63.791557  44.294412        NaN  98.185186  38.867028
1929-01-02  78.603241  53.351780  57.597027  92.448175   7.008877
1929-01-03   8.829794   2.013333  83.047291  77.324770  86.368349
1929-01-04  98.977844  80.616881  45.235708  77.893620  11.876852
1929-01-05  63.785651  14.522579  94.945445  52.671519  41.668902
```

I ran it through something that looks like your `gen_a`, and then made a vectorized version that gets the same answer:

```py
logs = np.log(MA_a_csv / data)
ans = ((j > logs) & (logs > -j)).replace({True: 1, False: 0})
```

Where `ans` is

```
            0  1  2  3  4
1928-12-31  1  0  0  0  0
1929-01-01  0  0  0  0  0
1929-01-02  1  1  0  1  0
1929-01-03  0  1  1  1  1
1929-01-04  0  1  0  1  1
1929-01-05  1  0  1  1  1
```

`np.log` can operate on the whole array at once, and pandas is probably doing something fancy to vectorize the greater-than comparisons as well. The `&` is a bit-wise and, so it's just checking that both conditions are true for each position.

And this runs ~180 times faster than my version of `gen_a`, which didn't have the try/except or print statements, so it should be an even greater improvement for your code.

You also don't need the `.replace({True: 1, False: 0})` part - in Python `1 == True` is True, as is `0 == False`, so you should be able to use them interchangeably.

Let me know if you have any issues with that. For further reading, I suggest Tom Augspurger's Modern Pandas articles - particularly applicable is the [Fast Pandas](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance) section.

Comment: Wow -- this worked perfectly and crunched all the data in seconds. I was hoping there was a solution like this that could operate on the whole array at once. All I can say is thanks so much; you just saved me hours and hours! Looking forward to taking a look at your suggested reading.

Comment: That answer is so pretty and perfect I could cry! Nice job on the vectorization

Answer (score 0):

Combining two short comments into an answer.

1) The statement

```
j > math.log(
   MA_a_csv.loc[date, security]/
   data.loc[date, security]) > -j
```

can be simplified slightly by doing `abs`, e.g. `j > abs(...)`

and might be sped up significantly by computing the log once separately and taking advantage of the fact that `log(a/b) == log(a) - log(b)`.

Even if the calculation is only done once for a cell, you might be able to calculate it and write it back out, to speed up re-runs.

2) If you have those print statements in your actual code they will take a very sizable chunk of the total time.

Comment: I do have the print statements in my actual code. I incorrectly presumed their overhead would be negligible. I also feel like an idiot now not thinking about just using abs()... Thanks for the suggested edits!

Comment: Since the indices are the same for the DFs in question, I really don't see why you would need to loop at all. Pandas is built on top of numpy, which makes broadcasting things like `abs` and `np.log` massively efficient. Maybe you could combine this with my earlier comment, `np.log(df1/df2)` and `abs`

Comment: @G.Anderson is absolutely right on that.  Any time you are writing a loop by hand you are going to be way slower than the built in operations (and it keeps you from doing something like putting a print in the tight loop ^^)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps use `chunksize` argument when reading csv. You'll need to play around to determine best size to use but i hear a good rule of thumb is set it to a size of half of your available memory.

```
df = pd.read_csv("your.csv", chucksize=memory/2)
```

when writing your results back to file you'll need to ensure append argument set:

```
df.to_csv("yourresults.csv", mode='a')
```

Either delete the file each time you run your code or ensure the first call of `to_csv()` is done in write mode (default).

Other options i'd try:

1) Use a cloud resource such as AWS EC2 and purchase a high spec high memory machine, transfer your data and code over to it and have it run your code. It should be a lot quicker.

2) I'd be looking at dividing the load across multiple machines using something like Pyspark but this might take a little while to come upto speed with if not familiar already.

Good luck!

Comment: Doing this on an undergrad budget... AKA $0. Thanks for the response -- I'll look at using option #2 with my laptop!

Comment: Edited to include chunksize option

Comment: It looks to me that you could speed up things getting rid of the two loops.
Create a [mcve](/help/mcve) with a smaller df let's say 5*10. Then we can see if it possible to vectorialize your function. This could give you a massive boost.

Comment: Then instead of pyspark, which could be a pain to set, you could have a look at dask.

Comment: @burlap101 this would be a good answer if the dataset were larger, or if the machine were running out of memory